# Python 3 library for working code-first with Sqlite

Tags: sqlite, python-3.x, code-first

Is there a Python 3 library that allows working with SQL databases using a code-first approach?

By code-first I understand being able to infer the DB schema from a set of classes and to generate DDL queries to create the DB objects if needed.

I'm particularly interested in working with a Sqlite database.

Comment: Please note that SQLite is not spelled with 2 L's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) supports Python 3. It also support SQLite, and defining the schema as Python classes, so it seems like the perfect fit for your requirements.